# Validating multiple columns with one validation method

Tags: vba, excel

This should be a simple fix, but I'm new to the VBA world and programming in general. This is the code I have to validate a specific column that holds an entry value from a survey. The value possibilities for some of the survey questions are the same, and I don't want to copy-and-paste the same code for every question and then change the column letter and number. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this.

Specifically, I want column I through column AC to be validated against the case seen below. I'd really like to keep this code as simple as possible. Thanks so much.

I like the method I am using right now, but if this needs to be rebuilt from the ground up, then so be it.

```
Sub MyCheck()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case Cells(i, 9).Value
            Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "88", "99"
                Cells(i, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Case Else
               Cells(i, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly then why VBA code and not Conditional Formatting?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, there are a few other validation groupings that I want to apply to different columns, and I'd like for all of this to happen at the press of a button across all worksheets. Also, I really want to improve my VBA abilities. If Conditional Formatting is the best route, then I'll be sure to look into that again. I just couldn't get the results I wanted.

Comment: Yes conditional formatting is the best and Non VBA way of handling it. You don't even need to press a button for this. As soon as the values will change in the cell, the color will change automatically. However if you still want a code based on your code then I can give that to you as well...

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, I'd like to see some code. But I think I will try working with the conditional formatting as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Also, validation from conditional formatting is overwritten when something is pasted into the cell.

Comment: So do a `pastespecial values` instead of pasting ;)

Comment: True. I'm just not the one who will be working within the file, so I'd rather have a function that could operate after the fact in the event someone forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyCheck()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ColLetter As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> From Col B to Col AC
        For i = 2 To 29
            ColLetter = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)

            '~~> Find the last row of the releavnt column
            lRow = .Range(ColLetter & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> Set your range
            Set rng = .Range(ColLetter & "2:" & ColLetter & lRow)

            '~~> Remove all the color. Note we are not doing this
            '~~> in the loop
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

            For Each aCell In rng
                Select Case aCell.Value
                Case 1 To 5, 88, 89
                Case Else
                    aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End Select
            Next
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I like this. Conditional formatting was still not working for me.